# Java: ¿Cómo cambiar dinámicamente background EditText en clase aparte?

Tags: java, clase, edittext, lambda

**Hola compañeros!** Estoy casi seguro que mi pregunta es bastante ingenua, pero échenme una mano, que estoy aprendiendo!

**OBJETIVO.** Tengo varios EditText y me gustaría ponerles un background rojo en caso que validen mal (validan mal cuando contienen cadenas vacías)

**CÓMO LO ESTOY HACIENDO.** Aquí va mi código, el cual funciona perfecto:

```
if (miEditText.getText().toString().trim().equals("")) {
    miEditText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_red);
}
else {
    miEditText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_white);
}
```

**PROBLEMA.** Si tengo 15 EditText, tengo que repetir este código 15 veces, lo cual quiero evitar.

**CÓMO QUIERO HACERLO.** La idea es armar una clase que se encargue de hacer esto, de tal modo que yo simplemente le pase como parámetro el EditText en cuestión y ya. Esta es mi clase:

```
public class Helpers {
    public static void validarEditText(EditText editText) {
        if (editText.getText().toString().trim().equals("")) editText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_red);
        else editText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_white);
    }
}
```

Utilizo la clase de este modo:

```
miBoton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Helpers->validarEditText(et_nombre);
    }
});
```

Al utilizar la clase de este modo, saltan 2 problemas:

**Error 1:** *Lambda expressions not supported at language level 7*. Este problema se arregló agregando lo siguiente al build.gradle (Module: app)

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

**Error 2:** *not a statement*. El cual apunta justo a: *Helpers->validarEditText(et_nombre)*.

¿Alguna idea de cómo solucionar este embrollo?

Comment: ¿Por qué no simplemente *Helpers.validarEditText(et_nombre)*? Así es como se invoca a un método estático. Las lambdas son una forma de definir una clase con un único método (no exactamente, pero para que te hagas una idea), pero no invocan ese método.

Comment: Y por supuerto, tendrás que obtener la referencia al *EditText* para invocar el método; desde tu código no está claro qué se supone qué es *et_nombre*.

Comment: @SJuan76 ¡Ajajja, no puedo creerlo, tienes razón! ¿Por qué utilicé el símbolo -> para llamar al método? Vengo de PHP, y así es como se hace allá, así que supongo que simplemente se me cruzaron los lenguajes. Increíble, gracias. +1.

Answer (score 0):

@SJuan76 respondió esta pregunta, cito su respuesta:

> ¿Por qué no simplemente Helpers.validarEditText(et_nombre)? Así es
>   como se invoca a un método estático. Las lambdas son una forma de
>   definir una clase con un único método (no exactamente, pero para que
>   te hagas una idea), pero no invocan ese método.

Como decía, vengo de PHP, y ahí llamas a un método así: **MiClase->miMetodo()**. Claramente se me me cruzaron los lenguajes, y no me di cuenta precisamente porque Java no impidió hacer esa jugada. Supongo que hacer eso (llamar a un método mediante la flecha), es un modo de hacer una expresión lamda.

Ok, algo más aprendimos hoy.